# Extension icons in Chrome for Mac have disappeared

Tags: mac, google-chrome, browser-addons, icons

On my new MacBook Pro running Snow Leopard 10.6.2 and Google Chrome for Mac, 5.0.307.11 beta, some (but not all) of the icons for extensions have disappeared.  I can tell SOMETHING is still there, because the space is occupied and you can see it indent as you mouse over it.  You can also see the name of the extension pop up in a balloon below.

But the extension icon is invisible and the extension itself doesn't work.

Right now it's happened with Google Translate, the show-in-IE extension, Wikipedia Chromium, Send with GMail and Clip to Evernote.

The LastPass and Feedly extension icons are still visible.

Any ideas on how to get them back and stop this from happening again?

Comment: Doesn't seem like this is just limited to Mac, happened to me on Windows when updating to 21.0.1180.60

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to deactivating the plugins and downloading it again. This can happen when you upgrade to a higher version when extensions are enabled